# Yahoo approving spam SPF to be sent from another email server

Tags: spam-prevention, yahoo-mail

I have a friend with a Yahoo mail account. She noticed that friends are receiving emails from her that contain spam links.

I looked at the header for the email and it's clear that the emails didn't come from Yahoo at all. Someone is simply spoofing her email address as the sender. What is strange is that Yahoo is happily approving this within their Sender Policy Framework.

It seems that it's using the email address suffix (I've replaced the real address with **myemailaddress@** from *yahoo.co.uk* to *eigbox.net*). Then it's being approved.

```
Delivered-To: myfriend@example.com
Received: by 10.140.22.5 with SMTP id 5csp432449qgm;
        Wed, 12 Nov 2014 02:02:49 -0800 (PST)
X-Received: by 10.236.0.200 with SMTP id 48mr41877982yhb.79.1415786569453;
        Wed, 12 Nov 2014 02:02:49 -0800 (PST)
Return-Path: <SRS0=yEirhN=AC=yahoo.co.uk=myemailaddress@eigbox.net>
Received: from bosmailout04.eigbox.net (bosmailout04.eigbox.net. [66.96.188.4])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTP id z3si40854204qaj.112.2014.11.12.02.02.49
        for <myfriend@example.com>;
        Wed, 12 Nov 2014 02:02:49 -0800 (PST)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of SRS0=yEirhN=AC=yahoo.co.uk=myemailaddress@eigbox.net designates 66.96.188.4 as permitted sender) client-ip=66.96.188.4;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of SRS0=yEirhN=AC=yahoo.co.uk=myemailaddress@eigbox.net designates 66.96.188.4 as permitted sender) smtp.mail=SRS0=yEirhN=AC=yahoo.co.uk=myemailaddress@eigbox.net;
       dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=yahoo.co.uk
Received: from bosmailscan01.eigbox.net ([10.20.15.1])
    by bosmailout04.eigbox.net with esmtp (Exim)
    id 1XoUlF-0002D8-8I
    for myfriend@example.com; Wed, 12 Nov 2014 05:02:49 -0500
Received: from [10.115.3.31] (helo=bosimpout11)
    by bosmailscan01.eigbox.net with esmtp (Exim)
    id 1XoUlF-0008UD-6a
    for myfriend@example.com; Wed, 12 Nov 2014 05:02:49 -0500
Received: from bosauthsmtp17.yourhostingaccount.com ([10.20.18.17])
    by bosimpout11 with 
    id Ea2l1p00M0N5uqq01a2oP7; Wed, 12 Nov 2014 05:02:49 -0500
X-Authority-Analysis: v=2.1 cv=GL6GE49K c=1 sm=1 tr=0
 a=f4kFLigMKr8AH7rIJ//qJA==:117 a=Ucc0vwuYEp1m9x8+LX/f5w==:17 a=pq4jwCggAAAA:8
 a=QPcu4mC3AAAA:8 a=z2mATNc-qwoA:10 a=jPJDawAOAc8A:10 a=BrDiTsk0AAAA:8
 a=Cxjgj1NQAAAA:8 a=r77TgQKjGQsHNAKrUKIA:9 a=9iDbn-4jx3cA:10 a=cKsnjEOsciEA:10
 a=SY3lr0oAAAAA:8 a=CRZNYA-b5yKqdm_edGoA:9 a=wPNLvfGTeEIA:10 a=_-HxDMq7NvwA:10
 a=94I9395znJMA:10 a=lCXqaazKXwcA:10 a=Pxhz28JneigA:10
 a=BCZKLY6wCJ1nRXa06OcA:9 a=0w8mRm1Z2Dm4xiXH:21 a=QEXdDO2ut3YA:10
 a=_W_S_7VecoQA:10 a=_N9xK0t-9icA:10 a=GcQu3N70MHwA:10 a=HdbAwMqyR8wA:10
 a=vsz4heGSqEAA:10
Received: from [202.84.35.209] (port=59658 helo=mail.pinoylaptoprepairs.com)
    by bosauthsmtp17.eigbox.net with esmtpa (Exim)
    id 1XoUlA-0002so-SP; Wed, 12 Nov 2014 05:02:45 -0500
Message-ID: <6E91985BA52A0DC1C041DC10E638FD58@mail.pinoylaptoprepairs.com>
From: "My Real Name" <myemailaddress@yahoo.co.uk>
To: "Friend" <myfriend@example.com>
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?FW=3Achristian_6?=
Date: Tue, 12 Nov 2014 11:02:37 +0000
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
 boundary="----=_NextPart_000_BD7D_08CFD723.1B889F5C"
X-Priority: 3
X-MSMail-Priority: Normal
Importance: Normal
X-Mailer: Microsoft Windows Live Mail 16.4.3522.110
X-MIMEOLE: Produced By Microsoft MimeOLE V16.4.3522.110
X-EN-UserInfo: 9966b87bb763be7f77e4c657e3816d40:931c98230c6409dcc37fa7e93b490c27
X-EN-AuthUser: christian@pinoylaptoprepairs.com
Sender:  "angela lockwood" <myemailaddress@yahoo.co.uk>
X-EN-OrigIP: 202.84.35.209
X-EN-OrigHost: unknown
```

Is there somewhere in Yahoo's account settings that lets me prevent people using this account?

Surely the SPF should prevent this happening or is it simply a workaround that spammers use?

Answer (score 3):

## Yahoo doesn't use SPF to prevent spoofing

Yahoo's SPF record is `v=spf1 ptr:yahoo.com ptr:yahoo.net ?all`. The last part is the only relevant one: `?all` means that there is no SPF policy.

In short, Yahoo is instructing the receiving mail server that it can't use SPF to determine if it's spam and that some other anti-spam technique should be used.

I'm not an expert, but it seems to me that if Yahoo would have actually used a real policy here, a lot of spam could have been marked as such.

Answer (score -2):

Please ask your friend to enable to **SSL** in her yahoo mail account settings. Since then each and every mail will be sent over SSL connection which would filter all spaming activity with her Email ID. To do so, click the gear wheel in the upper right corner, select “Mail Options,” go to “Advanced Settings,” and click “Turn on SSL” as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

Hope this help!

Comment: We've get SSL set - but this doesn't resolve the issue of someone using another server to spoof the email address.